# How to change Jquery clone position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am created a dynamic clone html when click on plus icon. it's work fine but problem is when i click on plus button clone place after plus button but i want to change the clone position before plus icon.

### Here HTML Code

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 200px;">                                                                    
   <table class="" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody id="attendCourse">                                                                        
             <tr id="attendCourse0">                                                                    
               <td style="width: 85%;">                                                  
                  <input name="course" class="form-control" type="text">                                                                                        
               </td>
               <td>
                 <img id="addAttand" src="<?php echo ASSETS_URL; ?>admin/images/plus1.png">
               </td>                                                                 
             </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

### HTML Design Image

[image]

### Jquery Code

```
$(function() {
var $componentTB = $("#attendCourse"),
    $firstTRCopy = $("#attendCourse0").clone();
    $idVal = 1;

$("#addAttand").click(function() {
    var copy = $firstTRCopy.clone();         
    var newId = 'attendCourse' +$idVal;
    copy.attr('id', newId);
    $idVal += 1;
    copy.children('td').last().replaceWith("<td><div class=''><img onclick=\"remove('" + newId + "')\" src="+JS_SITEURL+"assets/admin/images/negative.png></div></td>");        
    $componentTB.append(copy);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [insertbefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) method of jquery.

```
copy.insertBefore($("#attendCourse0"));
```